# Custom field with a custom entity reference

Tags: entities

I have a custom content type 'project' with a title 'project_no'.
I am creating a custom field 'project_reference' to be used in other content types. It has few fields; one of them is an entity reference to 'project'.
I have this in my FieldType . php file:

```
$properties['project_no'] = DataDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Project No.'))
  ->setSetting('target_type','project')
  ->setSetting('handler','default');
```

how to display the widget as a drop list and to have it use auto complete to search/filter in contents of 'project'?
I want to be able to enter a character and it will filter the projects that contain that character.

Comment: I would extend entity reference field type and autocomplete widget from core and add the other (hopefully less complex) properties.

Comment: Thank you for replying.. although answer is very direct, but it is still not clear to me.. I am just beginning to delve in drupal  coding. :-)
I used drush to generate the custom module for the field, so I am moving forward from there

Comment: You can only drush generate compound fields with skalar properties. Unless you want to invest some time to investigate how for example the core file module extends entity reference field classes for its own file entity you might want to use paragraphs to combine complex field types.

Comment: If it's a content type, then why not use the standard field UI to add your field? The **Manage form display** UI should be able to accommodate all of your widget needs. If you need to bundle the field into a project, use Features or just export the config to your module.

Comment: @4k4 I am willing -and actually doing- investing time googling and searching youtube as well as scanning the core modules source files. But, being new to this with almost no 'proper' background in programming, other than what I taught myself over the years for personal needs and use, this make it a little more difficult to locate the exact information, or sometimes, to under it once located.

Comment: @4k4 This is why I ask for help every now and then.. not necessarily for the full code solution - although that would save a lot of time :-) - but rather for a guidance .. clear enough for me to follow, or for a reference to a guide to assist me

Comment: @Beau , well.. what I need is this: in 'several' custom content types, that are defined in code, I want to have an entity reference field named 'project_no' that is references a custom content type, named 'project', with a title named 'project_no'
once the specific project no is selected in the widget, other fields will be automatically populated based on that project, ie, name of client of the project, location of the project etc. These are displayed for information and reference.
The user then will enter values for other fields specific to each content type

Comment: @Beau Since, this collection of fields: ('Project No' reference entity field, client Name, Location) are repeated in several custom content types, I thought it is only appropriate to make them as a custom field and collect all the related logic code in one place

Comment: Have you considered using the Paragraphs module? Paragraphs work nicely as sub-entities to content types and other entities. Please see my answer to this question for information on how to programmatically generate/assign paragraph entities: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/298644/67688

Comment: @Beau, yes I've considered Paragraphs. In fact it was my 1st option, with almost no code, using exported config
btw. your linked answer looks very clear, which I will try myself anyway

Comment: There are 2 reasons for considering custom fields:
1- I want to learn how to do it. I am not a programmer and I am not doing this for profit, in fact I am spending money to learn, buying books and subscribing to websites. It is ok but slow learning
2- I have a big csv file I will need to migrate. Migrating to paragraphs will require me to learn more stuff at the same time to do a single task.. which I would rather prefer to avoid now.

Comment: I understand your points completely. I'd like to challenge one of your presumptions, which is that using Paragraphs will add complication. I would argue that it will reduce complication, since Paragraphs offers much of what you want. I do, of course, understand wanting to learn how to do things by hand, but learning to choose the right tools for the job is equally as important. Feeds and Paragraphs are mature, well-documented modules whose code bases are worth studying, and I think would enhance your learning by simultaneously giving you a working example as well as a peek under the hood.